# how to use session ids for authentication purpose

Tags: php, security, session

I am using just session variables `$_SESSION['user_id']` and `$_SESSION['passwd']` to store the id and password of user once when he logs in.

I am just checking these two variables with database each time the user moves to a new php page for authentication. Actually I didnt know about `session_id()` .

I dont think what i am doing for authentication is the right way. I feel that there is something to be done with `session_id` for security stuff.

and one more doubt- can these session variables be easily hacked when I use the session variables by the way i mentioned

What should I do?

Comment: Go through with some tutorial on Session management, PHP authentication etc would be more helpful

Answer (score 4):

An attacker cannot easily change or read your $_SESSION variables, as long as there is no other vulnerability present, but it is general bad practice to store a password any longer than necessary on the server for several reasons.

It is sufficient to check the password once when the user logs in. Afterwards you only need to store the authenticated user_id in the session. You have to know who the session belongs to, to grant the necessary permissions to this specific user. But you do already know that the user submitted the correct password, otherwise you wouldn't have stored his user_id in the session in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

For basic authentication your approach of storing the user id is fine. 
However, you don't need to store the password while the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

You should only authenticate against the database once, then store the result in the $_SESSION var. Example:

```
if ($user_and_pass_ok) {
  $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.
`$_SESSION['user_id']` is only variable you need.

```
if (empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
   die("access denied");
}
```

to check if user is authenticated.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to check everytime the user moves to a new php.
Once user authenticates, store the session_id in `$_SESSION['session_id']` for example. After that all you need to do is check if `$_SESSION['session_id']` is set. If it is, it means user is "logged in".

Hope it helps.

Comment: can this $_SESSION['session_id'] be hacked easily and be changed by a hacker to view another user's page??

Comment: If you want to make it more secure, create a cipher using a seed string, username and session_id and store it in $_SESSION['auth'] for example.... so you will have to check if $_SESSION['auth'] is set and also if it's value matches the cipher....

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand it little bit. hoe to match it with cipher. pls giv a mini explanation

Comment: if (isset($_SESSION['auth']) && ($_SESSION['auth'] == md5($username.$_session_id.$seed)) {
    echo "User logged in";
}

Comment: i get abt checking whether it is set or not , but how to match it with the cipher is my problem . I dono may sound silly , because i am a beginner

Comment: $seed is a string defined by you... could be "12-93ASDrhnt=."

Comment: If you are a beginner, don't start with user authentication.